# Tesseract.js for large files

Tags: javascript, image, ocr, tesseract, crop

I want to extract the text of a really large image, *like 1440 x 500,000 pxl or larger*.
My idea is to first crop the image because it has some unnecessary white space, I can remove about *60%* horizontally but none on the vertical axes.

It would be a great plus to also be able to cut the height into pieces of *85pxl* each so I can get an output for every row and not one big output at the end.

*Please ask more questions if you don't understand.
Any answer is really appreciated.*